# Line breaks in phpStorm are removed

Tags: php, ftp, newline, phpstorm

I am using phpStorm to edit some files. They appear fine in phpStorm, but when i open them in notepad everything is on one line. So for example this:

```
<?php
include('hello.php');
print 'test';
?>
```

Will become :

```
<?phpinclude('hello.php');print 'test';?>
```

Obviously, this causes error. Why is this happening and how can i restore my files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. The line breaks were not in windows format. In phpStorm, this was solved like this:

1. Select a file or directory in the Project tool window.
2. Choose File | Line Separators on the main menu, and then select the desired line ending style from the sub-menu.

You can read this, and more about line separators in phpstorm here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-line-separators.html